# Combine two CSS selectors with same name using SASS

Tags: css, sass

I have the following two .scss-files:
* _nav-critical.scss
* _nav.scss

In `_nav-critical.scss` I have this:

```
.nav-item {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

while in `_nav.scss` I have this:

```
@import "_nav-critical";

.nav-item {
  transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
}
```

My desired result in my css-file is this:

```
.nav-item {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
}
```

But what I get is this:

```
.nav-item {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
}

.nav-item {
  transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
}
```

Is there any way I can do this? The purpose is to be able to inline the critical stuff in the head and load everything through something like loadCSS and save to localStorage/cache, so I don't have to inline styles if the CSS is already cached/saved.

Thanx!

Comment: use [mixins](http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-6) instead

Comment: Using mixins doesn't seem the right solution to this, as it's not something that I'll be re-using. Maybe if you can provide an example of how it would make sense..?

Answer (score 0):

Sass has no functionality for "merging" duplicate selectors. You'll need to find another utility to do this after the CSS has been compiled.

For example you can use csscss plugin: https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-csscss

Regards.

Comment: Here's a benchmark of different minifiers. Csscss not included unfortunately. https://github.com/GoalSmashers/css-minification-benchmark